# XSL1.0 excluding previous nodes

Tags: xslt-1.0

I'm constrained to vanilla XSLT1.0 (no extensions) and MSXML transforms

Completely stumped on a problem.

I have an XML that I need to create HTML output from. Nodes need to be sorted by version_code then by despatch_tape_colour, BUT then grouped by address_line_1 (easier to look at image below to see: cream colored headings are group headers)

```
<order>
   <order_no>16292</order_no>
   <job_no>16292</job_no>
   <loads>
      <LoadID>10</LoadID>
      <load_seq>10</load_seq>
      <load_address_1>731 Fraser Street</load_address_1>
      <load_haulier>Purolator</load_haulier>
      <load_splits>
         <load_split_id>10</load_split_id>
         <load_split_description>Prince Rupert Northern View</load_split_description>
         <version_code>Z1</version_code>
         <despatch_tape_colour>FLAT</despatch_tape_colour>
      </load_splits>
   </loads>
   <loads>
      <LoadID>11</LoadID>
      <load_seq>11</load_seq>
      <load_address_1>8506 Main Street</load_address_1>
      <load_haulier>Purolator</load_haulier>
      <load_splits>
         <load_split_id>11</load_split_id>
         <load_split_description>*</load_split_description>
         <version_code>Z1</version_code>
         <despatch_tape_colour>FLAT</despatch_tape_colour>
      </load_splits>
   </loads>
   <loads>
      <LoadID>19</LoadID>
      <load_seq>19</load_seq>
      <load_address_1>130 - 766 Cliveden Place</load_address_1>
      <load_haulier>Purolator</load_haulier>
      <load_splits>
         <load_split_id>19</load_split_id>
         <load_split_description>*</load_split_description>
         <version_code>Z1</version_code>
         <despatch_tape_colour>FLAT</despatch_tape_colour>
      </load_splits>
   </loads>
   <loads>
      <LoadID>123</LoadID>
      <load_seq>123</load_seq>
      <load_address_1>100 Railway Avenue West</load_address_1>
      <load_haulier>Purolator</load_haulier>
      <load_splits>
         <load_split_id>123</load_split_id>
         <load_split_description>*</load_split_description>
         <version_code>Z2</version_code>
         <despatch_tape_colour>FLAT</despatch_tape_colour>
      </load_splits>
   </loads>
   <loads>
      <LoadID>124</LoadID>
      <load_seq>124</load_seq>
      <load_address_1>130 - 766 Cliveden Place</load_address_1>
      <load_haulier>Purolator</load_haulier>
      <load_splits>
         <load_split_id>124</load_split_id>
         <load_split_description>*</load_split_description>
         <version_code>Z2</version_code>
         <despatch_tape_colour>FLAT</despatch_tape_colour>
      </load_splits>
   </loads>
</order>
```

In the image below you can see that 19 and 124 are grouped together as they both have same address_line_1 (it's required that 19 appears in the order it does). The problem is that node 124 then appears later and is again grouped with 19. What I need to do is ignore load_split_ids that have already been iterated over or included in a previous group.

The only other way I can think of (maybe :-)) solving it is to create and msxml nodeset and then iterate over that, but I'd like to see if there's an alternative method

[image: problem]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>


    <xsl:variable name="template_version">1.0.0.26</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="template_date">7th August 2016</xsl:variable>
    <!-- Based on Shipments v1.0.0.8 -->

     <xsl:variable name="currency_symbol"/>



    <xsl:key name="unique_load_addresses_version_format" match="/order/loads[starts-with(load_haulier, 'Purolator')]/load_splits" use="concat(../load_address_1,'_',version_code,'_',despatch_tape_colour)"/>


    <xsl:include href="Globals_pdf.xsl"/>   
    <xsl:template match="order">
        <html>
            <head>
                <!-- PrinceXML: Adding UTF-8 stops browser interpreting &#160; as A-circumflex followed by a <space> -->
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/> 
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-2"/>
                <style type="text/css">



                    body {font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:8pt;}
                    h1 {font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 22pt; font-weight: bold; margin: 0 0 10px 0;}
                    .outer { width: 100%; }
                    .tax { width: 100%;}
                    table {font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;cellspacing: 0px; cellpadding: 0px;  border-width: 0; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0px; width: 100%; }
                    td {vertical-align: top; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; padding: 5px 1px 5px 1px; font-size: 8pt; border-width: 1pt; border-style: solid;  border-color: <xsl:value-of select="$color2"/>;  }
                    th {text-align: left; vertical-align: bottom; background-color: LightSteelBlue; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;  font-size: 8pt; font-weight: normal; padding: 5px 1px 5px 1px; border-width: 1pt; border-style: solid;  border-color: <xsl:value-of select="$color2"/>; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0px; color: black;}


                    .bold { font-weight: bold; }
                    .grey {background-color: #dddddd; }

                    .proforma  { color:  black; }
                    .heading { vertical-align: bottom; text-align: center;}
                    .bottom_center { vertical-align: bottom;  text-align: center; }
                    .top_center { vertical-align: top; text-align: center; }
                    .top_left { vertical-align: top; text-align: left; }
                    .middle_left { vertical-align: middle; text-align: left; }
                    .middle_center { vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; }
                    .top_right { vertical-align: top;  text-align: right; }
                    .bottom_left { vertical-align: bottom;  text-align: left; }
                    .bottom_right { vertical-align: bottom; text-align: right; }

                    .left_indent {padding-left: 70px;}
                    .top_indent {padding-top: 35px;}



                    .label {font-weight: bold; width: 15%; padding-top: 2px; padding-bottom: 2px; padding-right: 5px; text-align: right; width: 30%; font-size: 12pt;}
                    .contents {padding-left: 5mm; width: 30%; padding-top: 2px; padding-bottom: 2px; width: 70%; font-size: 12pt;}

                    hr {border: none; background-color: black; height: 0.5pt;} 
                    .first_row { border-top: 2pt solid red; }
                    .red {color: #aa0000; }

                </style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <table class="loads" style="">

                    <tr>
                        <th>S/P/I</th>
                        <th>Zone</th>
                        <th>Format</th>
                        <th>Address</th>
                        <th>Carrier</th>
                     </tr>

                    <xsl:for-each select="/order/loads[starts-with(load_haulier, 'Purolator')]/load_splits[generate-id() = generate-id(key('unique_load_addresses_version_format', concat(../load_address_1,'_',version_code,'_',despatch_tape_colour))[1])]">
                        <xsl:sort select="concat(version_code,'_',despatch_tape_colour)" data-type="text" />
                        <xsl:variable name="curr_address" select="../load_address_1"/>

                        <tr>
                            <td style="background-color: #fdf5e6; color: blue; border-top: 2px solid grey">Load/LoadSplitID: <xsl:value-of select="../LoadID"/>/<xsl:value-of select="load_split_id"/></td>
                            <td style="background-color: #fdf5e6; color: blue; border-top: 2px solid grey"><xsl:value-of select="version_code"/></td>
                            <td style="background-color: #fdf5e6; color: blue; border-top: 2px solid grey"><xsl:value-of select="despatch_tape_colour"/></td>
                            <td style="background-color: #fdf5e6; color: blue; border-top: 2px solid grey"><xsl:value-of select="../load_address_1"/></td>
                            <td style="background-color: #fdf5e6; color: blue; border-top: 2px solid grey"></td>
                        </tr>

                        <xsl:for-each select="/order/loads[starts-with(load_haulier, 'Purolator') and load_address_1 = $curr_address]/load_splits">
                            <xsl:sort select="concat(version_code,'_',despatch_tape_colour)" data-type="text" order="ascending" />
                            <xsl:variable name="part_ref" select="load_despatch_code"/>
                            <xsl:variable name="line_type">
                                <xsl:choose>
                                    <xsl:when test="position() = 1">S</xsl:when>
                                    <xsl:otherwise>P</xsl:otherwise>
                                </xsl:choose>
                            </xsl:variable>
                            <tr>
                                 <td>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="style">
                                        <xsl:choose>
                                            <xsl:when test="position()=1">color: red; border-top: 2px solid black</xsl:when>
                                            <xsl:when test="position()=last()">color: black;</xsl:when>
                                        </xsl:choose>
                                    </xsl:attribute>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="load_split_id"/>

                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="style">
                                        <xsl:choose>
                                            <xsl:when test="position()=1">color: red; border-top: 2px solid black</xsl:when>
                                            <xsl:when test="position()=last()">color: black;</xsl:when>
                                        </xsl:choose>
                                    </xsl:attribute>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="version_code"/>

                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="style">
                                        <xsl:choose>
                                            <xsl:when test="position()=1">color: red; border-top: 2px solid black</xsl:when>
                                            <xsl:when test="position()=last()">color: black;</xsl:when>
                                        </xsl:choose>
                                    </xsl:attribute>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="despatch_tape_colour"/>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="style">
                                        <xsl:choose>
                                            <xsl:when test="position()=1">color: red; border-top: 2px solid black</xsl:when>
                                            <xsl:when test="position()=last()">color: black;</xsl:when>
                                        </xsl:choose>
                                    </xsl:attribute>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="../load_address_1"/>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:attribute name="style">
                                        <xsl:choose>
                                            <xsl:when test="position()=1">color: red; border-top: 2px solid black</xsl:when>
                                            <xsl:when test="position()=last()">color: black;</xsl:when>
                                        </xsl:choose>
                                    </xsl:attribute>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="../load_haulier"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
```

Any XSL wizards, got any suggestions?

TIA

Mark

Comment: Could you (a) minimize the example to only what's necessary to demonstrate the problem and (b) explain the required logic in words? How would one accomplish this task manually? -- I am especially puzzled by your requirement to sort first, then group. Does that mean you want to group only within sorted groups? I don't see that in your output (as far as I can understand it).